# Ужасная производительность CollectionView внутри StackLayout на Android

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Проблема такова:
На Андройде CollectionView работает очень быстро, но если запихнуть его внутрь StackLayout, который в свою очередь находиться внутри ScrollView, то будет такая ужасная производительность, что приложение просто вылетает при прокрутке CollectionView.
Причем проблема только на Андройде, на Windows всё отлично.
Стоит отметить, что это происходит только тогда, когда в ItemTemplate будет находиться Image + Label или + ещё что-нибудь. Если убрать Image, то производительность становиться хорошей.
Если кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался, то как вы это исправили?

---

Я заметил, что если добавить к CollectionView какое-либо значение в HeightRequest, то плохая производительность уйдёт. Но мне надо отображать Footer, который почему-то вообще никаким образом не отображается на Windows, а на Андройде он пропадает, если в ItemsSource что-то добавляется, а потом заново появляется, если опять что-то добавить в ItemsSource. Поэтому было решено поместить CollectionView внутрь ScrollView + StackLayout и добавить туда ещё один StackLayout, который заменяет забаганный Footer у CollectionView, но это вызывает плохую производительность на андроиде.

Comment: Проблема в том, что и у scroll view, и у collection view содержатся лисенеры касания, такие объекты лучше не накладывать поверх друг друга. Насколько я понимаю, вам нужно сделать одновременно вертикальные и горизонтальные ползунки? Если они оба в одном направлении, то лучше использовать один из них.